Ignoring type in Fail method in standard C# result class
I've worked with Result classes for many years and when I was exposed to C# the first encounter I had was with John Ottosson result class. This is the version of the result class I used as a basis for my own purposes, and has served me well over the years. But it's not without its flaws and I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out more elegant ways to make it work.
Heres a typical implementation of a C# result class.
public class Error
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
   //left out other properties for brevity
}

public class Result
{
    //If there are no errors, then it is a successful call
    public bool IsSuccessful => Errors?.Any() ?? true;
    public IReadOnlyList<Error>? Errors { get; set; }
    
    public static Result<T> Success<T>(T data)
    {
        return new Result<T>
        {
            Data = data,
            Errors = null
        };
    }
    
    public static Result<T> Fail<T>(Error error)
    {
        return new Result<T>
        {
            Errors = new List<Error> { error }
        };
    }
}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

The biggest thing that bugs me in that you have to give a type to the Fail method even though the Fail method is just going to cause T to be null.
I'm aware its kind of a nit-picking issue but it's one I've wondered about for years. Its annoying in its use and a little misleading having to write Result.Fail<MyDto?>("Some Error Message"). If someone does have a better approach to this I would love to hear it. I've moved this class over to typescript a few times just for side projects and it works so much better there.
UPDATE I've made a little progress with it by using OneOf(Thanks @Alejandro)
This doesn't compile but I'm getting closer perhaps.
public class Result
{
    //cut for brevity
    public static Result<EmptyResponse> Fail(Error error)
    {
        return new Result<EmptyResponse>
        {
            Errors = new List<Error> { error },
            Data = new EmptyResponse() //Errors here. See error below
        };
    }
}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
    public OneOf<T, EmptyResponse> Data { get; set; }
}

ERROR: Cannot convert source type 'Playground.EmptyResponse' to target type 'OneOf.OneOf<Playground.EmptyResponse,Playground.EmptyResponse>
Even though Data is OneOf T or EmptyResponse. It still wants the type information of T provided. So while the above doesn't compile, This would
    public static Result<T> Fail<T>(Error error)
    {
        return new Result<T>
        {
            Errors = new List<Error> { error },
            Data = new EmptyResponse()
        };
    }

Which is basically back at square one. Providing type information to Fail which doesn't need it.
Second Update I've found a decent solution using the OneOf library. I'll share it for anyone curious.
public class Result<TResult> : OneOfBase<TResult, IReadOnlyList<Error>>
{
    protected Result(OneOf<TResult, IReadOnlyList<Error>> _) : base(_)
    {
    }

    public bool IsSuccessful => IsT0;
    
    public TResult Data => AsT0;
    public IReadOnlyList<Error> Errors => AsT1;
    
    public static implicit operator Result<TResult> (TResult _) => new(_);
    public static implicit operator Result<TResult>(List<Error> _) => new Result<TResult>(_);
    public static implicit operator Result<TResult>(Error _) => new Result<TResult>(new List<Error>() { _ });
}

So with any given method you can return either a success or a fail without having to specify type information.
    public Result<string> TestSuccessful()
    {
        return "Yay it worked!";
    }

    public Result<string> TestFail()
    {
        return new Error() { Message = "Ahh idk what happened" };
    }

And then you can use it like so
var failResult = controller.TestFail();
var successResult = controller.TestSuccessful();

if (failResult.IsSuccessful)
    Console.WriteLine(failResult.Data);
else
    Console.WriteLine(failResult.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.Message);
if (successResult.IsSuccessful)
    Console.WriteLine(successResult.Data);
else
    Console.WriteLine(successResult.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.Message);

That seems to work fine. You can match on the Result to get the successful side or error side and you still get type information. So it checks all the boxes I believe.

I don't find your approach a bad thing, but if you want, you may look into the OneOf library that adds unions-ish types to c# and may come in handy here. Unions are the biggest feature Typescript has (as a "weaker" typed language) and c# doesn't that lets you implement a clean version of this.

I haven't heard of that library until recently. Are you suggesting using oneof library on its own entirely or use it in conjunction with this result class?

Not a very popular library BTW. I would use it in combination with your failure class, while using the real return value for the success case.

I see your point. But in my perfect world I would create an alias class for a null data. Something like EmptyResponse which could just hold an empty string array or something. That doesn't matter. Then I would say my Data is either the expected TResult or EmptyResponse. And my Fail method would just return a result with errors and data set to EmptyResponse

You could do that with the library I suggested, something like OneOf<TResult, EmptyResponse> meaning that your service returns either a TResult or an EmptyResponse. Your client code then handles both cases.

I updated the OP with results using that library. Unless there's something I'm missing it doesn't help too much. Though it does make it more clear in the type information when an error has occurred. But your still left with typing a fail with the type information of a success.

Could you please provide an example signature that you typically use with said result type? And a consumer that processes the result? I'm struggling with the inheritance there since everything ends up being Result<T> but this depends mostly on preferred usage patterns. Edit: Also, what version of C# are you interested in?

I'm on c# 12 with dotnet 8 currently. Heres a fiddle which highlights the process we use it in normally
https://dotnetfiddle.net/B3hWOa

Since you're on .NET 6+, you could also use constructors and target-typed new instead of those implicit casts in your update #2. But I really like the Error structure and how it's obvious, so I'd also use it. The only place where it won't work is passing it as a parameter, e. g. to Task.FromResult but I'm not really sure that scenario can be helped.

I'd probably add a Fail method to the Result so that I can create one from an error then you don't have to worry about implicit operators being the only way to create an instance of an error class. Either way I'm reasonably satisfied with the result. I really appreciate the nudges in the right direction from both of you. Thank you!

Why not just return Result from your Fail factory method?  Or you could use pattern matching on type for a more functional experience and remove Errors from a successful result the same way you want to remove Data from a failure result:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/IFYFHj
public interface IResult
{
}

public record SuccessResult : IResult
{
    public static readonly SuccessResult Instance = new();
}

public record SuccessResult<TData>( TData Data ) : SuccessResult;

public record FailureResult : IResult
{
    public static readonly FailureResult Instance = new();
}

public record FailureResult<TError>( IEnumerable<TError> Errors ) : FailureResult;

Usage:
var msg = result switch
{
    SuccessResult<int> sri => $"Successful with data {sri.Data}",
    SuccessResult sr => $"Successful with no data",
    FailureResult<int> fri => $"Failed with errors",
    FailureResult fr => $"Failed without errors",
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException( result.GetType().FullName ),
};


I've toyed around with solutions very similar to this one. And the main draw back is in your methods you have to declare the return type as IResult which makes it less obvious to consumers of the method what it should return. Everytime you use a method you'd have to dig into the method and see what its return type is which was something I'd dislike more then having to give type to a Result.Fail. After playing around with OneOf I found somewhat of a solution which is not all that different from yours but with type information and I put it in the OP
